# Access SQL update based on count results and conditional update

Tags: sql, join, conditional-statements, ms-access-2010

Yesterday I got help on this SQL statement and it's working fantastically...  Now I'm trying to use data from this query to update two columns on a different table.

Here is the query as I have it:

```
SELECT x.TechID,
       Count(*) AS cnt,
       tblEmployeeData.LName,
       tblEmployeeData.Pernr,
       tblEmployeeData.Occurrences,
       tblEmployeeData.Standing
FROM   tblEmployeeData
       INNER JOIN tblOccurrence AS x
         ON tblEmployeeData.TechID = x.TechID
WHERE  ( ( ( x.OccurrenceDate ) BETWEEN Dateadd("m", -6, Date()) AND Date() )
         AND ( ( EXISTS (SELECT *
                         FROM   tblOccurrence AS y
                         WHERE  y.TechID = x.TechID
                                AND Dateadd ("d", -1, x.[OccurrenceDate]) = y.[OccurrenceDate]) ) = False ) )
GROUP  BY x.TechID,
          tblEmployeeData.LName,
          tblEmployeeData.Pernr;
```

What I want to do is take the results and update the tblEmployeeData two columns.  One column (tblEmployeeData.Occorrences) will be the value represented by 'cnt' ... and then the tough part ... the column tblEmployeeData.Standing will be updated using the value from 'cnt' as follows:

```
0-3 = "Good"
4-5 = "Verbal Warning"
6-7 = "Written Warning"
8 = "Final Written Warning"
9+ = "Termination"
```

It's already a large SQL statement and this is going way above my head!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap a query in another query:

```
SELECT TechID, Rank FROM Rank,
(SELECT x.TechID, Count(*) AS cnt, tblEmployeeData.LName, 
    tblEmployeeData.Pernr, tblEmployeeData.Occurrences, tblEmployeeData.Standing
FROM tblEmployeeData
INNER JOIN tblOccurrence AS x ON tblEmployeeData.TechID = x.TechID
WHERE (((x.OccurrenceDate) Between DateAdd("m",-6,Date()) And Date())
  AND ((Exists     
    (SELECT * FROM tblOccurrence AS y  WHERE y.TechID = x.TechID AND DATEADD 
    ("d", -1, x.[OccurrenceDate]) = y.[OccurrenceDate]))=False))
GROUP BY x.TechID, tblEmployeeData.LName, tblEmployeeData.Pernr) a
WHERE a.Cnt BETWEEN Rank.Low And rank.High
```

The idea is that you use the query with a `Rank` table, like so:

```
Low High    Rank
0   3       Good
4   5       Verbal Warning
6   7       Written Warning
8   8       Final Written Warning
9   99      Termination
```

Edit re comments

This runs for me in a rough mock-up

```
SELECT a.TechID, tblRank.Rank FROM tblRank, (SELECT x.TechID, Count(*) AS cnt, tblEmployeeData.LName, 
    tblEmployeeData.Pernr, tblEmployeeData.Occurrences, tblEmployeeData.Standing
FROM tblEmployeeData
INNER JOIN tblOccurrence AS x ON tblEmployeeData.TechID = x.TechID
WHERE (((x.OccurrenceDate) Between DateAdd("m",-6,Date()) And Date()) AND ((Exists     
    (SELECT * FROM tblOccurrence AS y  WHERE y.TechID = x.TechID AND DATEADD 
    ("d", -1, x.[OccurrenceDate]) = y.[OccurrenceDate]))=False))
GROUP BY x.TechID, tblEmployeeData.LName, tblEmployeeData.Pernr, tblEmployeeData.Occurrences, tblEmployeeData.Standing) a
WHERE a.Cnt BETWEEN tblRank.Low And tblrank.High
```

Comment: OOOOhhhh... I see... that's pretty good thinking.  I like being reminded that there are a lot smarter people out there that can figure this stuff out much quicker than I could!... Thanks Remou

Comment: Flattery will get you everywhere :)

Comment: I just restarted work on this and thought I understood what I was supposed to do to get this working... looks like I was wrong.  I run the query and it prompts me for information; tblemployeedata.occurrences, cnt and tblRank.high... that's not what I want.  basically, this SQL statement will be called every time the DB is opened so that it updates every employee's "rank" in the system by counting occrrences, updating the employeedata.occurrences field; then updating the rank field based on the occurrences...

Comment: SELECT TechID, Rank FROM tblRank, (SELECT x.TechID, Count(*) AS cnt, EmployeeData.LName, EmployeeData.Pernr, EmployeeData.Occurrences, EmployeeData.Standing FROM tblEmployeeData INNER JOIN tblOccurrence AS x ON tblEmployeeData.TechID = x.TechID WHERE (((x.OccurrenceDate) Between DateAdd('m',-6,Date()) And Date())AND ((Exists (SELECT * FROM tblOccurrence AS y  WHERE y.TechID = x.TechID AND DATEADD ('d', -1, x.[OccurrenceDate]) = y.[OccurrenceDate]))=False))
GROUP BY x.TechID, tblEmployeeData.LName, tblEmployeeData.Pernr, tblEmployeeData.Standing) WHERE a.Cnt BETWEEN tblRank.Low And tlbRank.High

Comment: You have changed the inner query. You refer to tblEmployeeData and EmployeeData. You need to use the real table names.

Comment: You're edited answer asks me for the same 3 parameters... and depending on what I input, the output changes.

Comment: Check your table names. The above requires tables called tblRank, tblEmployeeData and tblOccurrence. Did the query you posted above run? Does it still?

Comment: I should say, does it run when you correct GROUP BY to GROUP  BY x.TechID,
          tblEmployeeData.LName,
          tblEmployeeData.Pernr, tblEmployeeData.Occurrences,
       tblEmployeeData.Standing

Comment: Yea, I have all those tables.  It runs if I answer the prompted questions.

Comment: Zamael, prompts mean that the query cannot find a field. You posted a query in your question, did it work? Does it still work?

Comment: Egg on face! ... double checked all tables and low and behold... I had  a field spelled incorrectly... :-[ ... sorry...   ... ...

Comment: Okay. It is generally considered bad design to store calculated fields in a table, especially when the calculation can easily be obtained from a query. If you must do this, consider http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff973807.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff945943.aspx. They may or may not suit.

Comment: That makes sense.  Its obvious I'm quite green at this... So basically if I can do the logic through queries it is a more efficient design. Thank you for your help Remou